# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis Error

Tags: java, oracle

I'd like to get the last available balance from a table when godownname and itemname are matched.

I tried some code. but i have a problem with `last_value()` function in Oracle.

I got the error:

> SEVERE: null
>       java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1017)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:655)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:249)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:566)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:215)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:58)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:776)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:897)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1034)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3820)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3867)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1502)

I don't know where is the Error?.
Can anyone help me?

Here is my code:

```
String updateQuery = "select last_value(availablebalance) ignore nulls over(order by receiveddate or transdate) from t_stocks_status where godownname = ? and itemname = ?";
ps = con.prepareStatement(updateQuery);
ps.setString(1, fromField);
ps.setString(2, itemName);
rs = ps.executeQuery();
if (rs.next()) {
availableQty = rs.getInt(1);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to query? the `over` clause doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: *order by receiveddate or transdate* What are you trying to do with it? It is syntactically incorrect. Post some sample data, explain the rules and show your desired output.

Comment: This is a transaction Table, here I want to get the last updated or inserted availablebalence field value from the table when godownname and itemnames are matched. ( consider that there are more transactions are done. In this environment get only the last available balance field value).

Answer (score 0):

Your order by clause is having problem.`over(order by receiveddate or transdate)`

it may be like `over(order by receiveddate,transdate)`

Take a look at Order by clause syntax from [oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefsqlj13658.html)--

> ORDER BY { column-Name | ColumnPosition | Expression }
>       [ ASC | DESC ]
>       [ NULLS FIRST | NULLS LAST ]
>       [ , column-Name | ColumnPosition | Expression 
>       [ ASC | DESC ]
>       [ NULLS FIRST | NULLS LAST ]
>       ] *